# Spring: @SessionAttributes vs HttpSession

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

What's difference between @SessionAttributes vs HttpSession?
Which of the two, keeps for more time an object in the session?
In which cases I have to use the one and in which cases the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@SessionAttributes enables persisting model attributes session between requests, and is meant to be specific per hanlder. The intent was to provide a construct that will be a step close towards implementing a conversation scope (shorter than session, longer than request). The need for conversational scope and why it is not fully available with @SessionAttributes is explained well in this [blog](http://duckranger.com/2012/11/add-conversation-support-to-spring-mvc/).

It enables the automatic storing of the matching model attributes (match is based on the name). The default storage is HttpSession but this can be configured differently also. The docs say

> Session attributes as indicated using this annotation correspond to a
>   specific handler's model attributes, getting transparently  stored in
>   a conversational session. Those attributes will be removed once  the
>   handler indicates completion of its conversational session.

This bit however *Those attributes will be removed once  the handler indicates completion of its conversational session.* does not happen automagically, and it is up to a developer to indicate the exit from the conversation by using *setComplete* on a *SessionStatus* instance. Otherwise the models attribute will remain in session, often an undesired side effect.

The easiest way to understand the difference is by observing the scope and the value of the model variable, model variable backed with @SessionAttribute, and the "normal" HttpSession variable.

Take a look at the two simple controllers

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("modelAndSession")
@RequestMapping("/sessionattr")
public class FirstController {
    protected static final String NEXT_VIEW = "next";
    @RequestMapping("/init")
    public String handlingMethod1( Model model, HttpSession session) {
        model.addAttribute(NEXT_VIEW, "/sessionattr/afterinit");
        session.setAttribute("session", "TRUE");
        model.addAttribute("modelAndSession", "TRUE");
        model.addAttribute("model", "TRUE");
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/afterinit")
    public String handlingMethod2(SessionStatus status, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(NEXT_VIEW, "/nosessionattr/init");
        //status.setComplete();
        return "index";
    }

}
```

the second controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/nosessionattr")
public class SecondController {
    protected static final String NEXT_VIEW = "next";
    @RequestMapping("/init")
    public String handlingMethod3(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(NEXT_VIEW, "/sessionattr/init");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

and the view that will trigger the flow

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<a href="${next}">Next step ${next}</a>
<hr/>
<table>
     <thead>
          <th>key</th> <th>Request scope</th> <th>Session scope</th>
     </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>model</td> <td>${requestScope.model}</td> <td>${sessionScope.model}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>model and session</td> <td>${requestScope.modelAndSession}</td> <td>${sessionScope.modelAndSession}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>session</td> <td>${requestScope.session}</td> <td>${sessionScope.session}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### The flow

Upon the initial request `/sessionattr/init` the view renders as follows

[image]

so the model variable is available in the request scope, the sessionattribute is available in both the request and the session scope and the "normal" session attribute available only in session scope

On the next request `/sessionattr/afterinit` the view renders as follows

[image]

so the model-only variable is gone, while the @SessionAttribute model attribute is pushed from the session to the model and persisted across requests. The next step will target a second controller `/nosessionattr/init`, and the view will render as follows

[image]

now the @SessionAttribute model object is gone from the model, but since the status.setComplete is not explicitely called it remained in the session as a normal variable

This is a specially confusing scenario as many expect that @SessionAttribute model object should be gone after switching handler, however unless explicitly cleared it remains in the session. Feel free to copy the snippets and investigate further the combination that confuses you

Comment: Why if i want to delete all the objects from httpsession i have to write session.invalidate() but if i want to delete all the object annotated by @Session attributes I have to write SessionStatus setComplete()?Are they stored in different places?I read the spring Api and it says "For permanent session attributes, e.g. a user authentication object, use the traditional session.setAttribute method instead" Why?

Comment: By default SessionAttributes are store in HttpSession (but this can be changed). Its not the matter of how they are stored, rather that they are a different things, SessionAttributes reads from the session, and stores to the model, and vice versa, so those are model attributes persisted in session. But session can hold other variables as well, that's why you have distinctive delete methods. SessionAttributes usually serves the purpose to persist data accross subsequent calls to the methods of the same contoller, as its scope is bound to the handler. While the scope of the session is wider

Comment: In my Spring MVC project I have annotated @SessionAttributes("user") in a controller .Why if ,in a method of the controller, i redirect to index.jsp(managed by another controller), I can see in this jsp the User's informations? Instead you said "serves the purpose to persist data accross subsequent calls to the methods of the same contoller".In my case the controllers are different..

Comment: the question deserved a better answer, what you're explaining is due to the fact that the jsp reads the info from the session. However, unless you second controllers also uses @SessionAttribute with the same key, the value won't be automatically pushed to model. Tried to explain it with the code

Comment: You said "They support a scope shorter than traditional session (the conversational scope)"  Is This for @SessionAttributes or for Model attributes?

Comment: I meant SessionAttributes, the model attributes have the shortest life span, they are request scoped. SessionAttributes extend the scope of the model attributes in a sense that they inject the model attributes in the model of all the methods of the same handler. Its the difference that you see in the second view. When you move to a different handler, the placing in the model won't happen, but the attribute will still be retained in session unless you call status.setComplete. Keep in mind that model attributes are kept in the request scope.

Comment: But ,if in the second controller, I have the "modelAndSession" attribute stored only in the session..how can this life be shorter than session attributes?It seems to me the same

Comment: yes, that's true, unless the you delete it from the session than its the same as the session varialble. But its an anti-pattern, with SessionAttributes you have a construct that helps you create the intermediary scope, but unless you don't call the setComplete, it becomes the classical session attribute

Comment: But also in the traditional session I can call  invalidate() method. Therefore,they are almost the same..In SessionAttribute I can put all types of variables, also an object?In Spring , in jsp page, i can't access to bean with scope=session,why? They are also stored in the session but i can't access to them..If I want to display The User's information(name,surname, and so on) in a jsp page , it's better that  I declare it as SessionAttributes("userObject") or it's better that I create a User bean with scope=session?

Comment: With the traditional session you can do all, and more than with SessionAttributes. However, its often tedious to use sessions to support a wizzard like multi-step process, yet perfectly convient to use the conversational scope. I've posted a link to a blog explaining the need for conversational, but yes, you can always lean on the traditional session to acheive the same

Comment: Thank you very much .Today I learned a lot from your explanations

Answer (score 0):

Master Slave has already answered the questions. There's one thing I would like to add about the difference between @SessionAttributes and HttpSession

Altough @SessionAttributes are saved in the HTTPSession - they will not disappear if calling HTTPSesssion#invalidate()
There will be a new session, but the variables marked as @SessionAttributes will persist and be copied into the new session.

So if need be to invalidate the session, or just if the @SessionAttributes themselves are not needed anymore in the conversation scope, then also inject the SessionStatus-interface into an appropriate handler-method, then call SessionStatus#setComplete()

I also rewrote the JSP-file provided by Master Slave, into a Thymeleaf-template. Same controller-classes can be used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="../sessionattr/init" data-th-href="@{${next}}">Next step [[${next}]]</a>
<hr>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>key</th>
            <th>Request Scope</th>
            <th>Session Scope</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>model</td>
            <td data-th-text="${#request.getAttribute('model')?: 'false'}">N/A</td>
            <td data-th-text="${#session.getAttribute('model')?: 'false'}">N/A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>modelAndSession</td>
            <td data-th-text="${#request.getAttribute('modelAndSession')?: 'false'}">N/A</td>
            <td data-th-text="${#session.getAttribute('modelAndSession')?: 'false'}">N/A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>session</td>
            <td data-th-text="${#request.getAttribute('session')}?: 'false'">N/A</td>
            <td data-th-text="${#session.getAttribute('session')}?: 'false'">N/A</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```