# Spring controller to work similarly to both GET and POST methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a method like below in my Spring application

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search-result-doctors", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getDoctorSearchResults(String LastName, String Hospital, String Specialty, String date1, ModelMap model) {
    //some logics

     return "doctorchannelling/search-result-doctors";
}
```

after going in to the page "search-result-doctors" when I press the just Enter in the URL it has to remain in the same page. Since it is a GET request I have written the same method again with a method value RequestMethod.GET.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search-result-doctors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getDoctorSearchResults(String LastName, String Hospital, String Specialty, String date1, ModelMap model) {
    //some logics

    return "doctorchannelling/search-result-doctors";
}
```

due to the unavailability of parameter values String LastName, String Hospital, String Specialty, String date1 in the GET request i'm getting a Exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How can I resolve this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide a full stacktrace and an example call to that specific URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @StanislavL is saying, you should annotate your parameters with `@RequestParam(required=false)`, so

```
public String getDoctorSearchResults(@RequestParam(required=false) String LastName,@RequestParam(required=false) String Hospital, @RequestParam(required=false) String Specialty, @RequestParam(required=false) String date1, ModelMap model) {
```

combined with the method annotation and NullPointer checkes as given by @StanislavL, should give you what you want

Comment: I'm using these parameter values to generate a dynamic page. So i need the parameters passed during the POST method in the GET method also.
when using @RequestParam(required=false) I'm not getting any parameter values in the GET request

Comment: On your POST request you can store you're parameters in session, and on the GET retrieve from it. Storing the parameters in session or [@SessionAttributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191798/spring-sessionattributes-vs-httpsession/27192130#27192130) is your only option, for the case you describe, 'cause pressing an enter on a browser will never submit the parameters again

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can define just one method to process both GET and POST

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search-result-doctors", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
```

If you get NPE somewhere in your **some logic** just check which parameters are empty.

Comment: how to know the type of request - whether it is post or get inside the controller method?