# How to use post redirect get using spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, redirect

I am trying to understand PRG pattern and created a simple form, which accepts name and age of user. And after submit i want it to display Welcome username, and on refreshing of tab it should maintain the same.But after refreshing it is displaying only Welcome. Here is the code

demoForm.jsp

```
<form action="/Spring_Hibernate_RegistrationAndLogin/prg1" method="post">
Name:  <input type="text" name="uname"><br/><br/><br/>
Age:   <input type="text" name="age"><br/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Done"/>
```

succes.jsp

```
<h3>Hello  ${name}</h3>
```

Controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="prg",method={RequestMethod.GET})
public ModelAndView demoForm(){
    System.out.println("in get");
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("demoForm");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/prg1",method={RequestMethod.GET})
public ModelAndView doGet(@ModelAttribute ("userName") String s){
    System.out.println("in get1");
    //String name=s;

    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("succes");
    model.addObject("name", s);
    return model;
}


@RequestMapping(value="/prg1",method={RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView doPost(@RequestParam(name = "uname") String s,final RedirectAttributes redirectAttribute){
    System.out.println("in post1");
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("redirect:/prg1");
    //model.addObject("uname", s);
    redirectAttribute.addFlashAttribute("userName",s);
    return model;
}
```

Any help will be appriciated . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash attributes are not saved between page refreshes. To achieve what you want, you can use session attributes. The simplest way to implement is to add @SessionAttributes("userName") on your controller class. Or you can manipulate it manually using the request object: request.getSession.setAttribute("userName",s);

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.can u please help me with code snippet.

Comment: Where your controller class is defined, just add: @SessionAttributes("userName") on the next line after the @Controller annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Either redirect to the completely new page which contains your success message, or store your success message as a [session attribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html) which has a shorter livecycle than an attribute which is set directly to the HTTP session. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191798/spring-sessionattributes-vs-httpsession)

Comment: i am redirecting to a completely new page succes.jsp. but not getting a desired output